# Which version of Eclipse is best for Phonegap?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I'm a dotnet developer and new to Eclipse. I'm using Eclipse Juno sdk 4.2  Android and Phonegap I have developed my first application using tutorials but with lots of difficulty. For example, there is no HTML syntax support in IDE.

What steps do I need to support HTML Intellisense and syntax highlighting like Eclipse Helios, maybe just like dotnet? I have downloaded Eclipse Helios but it does not support Android I think, gives error when downloading ADT tools, while if I try to download Phonegap direct it gives error "Android not install", something like that.

What would you suggest which eclipse version I use with what handy tools?

Comment: edit your question, it should be  which version not whcih versio

Answer (score 3):

The AppLaud Eclipse plugin for PhoneGap requires at minimum of Eclipse 3.6 (Helios).  It does not work with 3.5 (Galileo).  The plugin also works with 3.7 (Indigo).

So its better to have an eclipse of version higher than 3.5

It's true that you can work around not having the plugin, but it makes PhoneGap project start-up much easier.

and check this link for phonegap

http://www.phonegap.com/developer#android

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/australia/set-up-an-environment-for-android-eclipse-and-phonegap/207

Comment: can you send me the download link of helios i cant find it in download page silly of me

Comment: the two links you gave me telling to download eclipse classic no info on helios

Comment: check this link and I dont know which machine(windows/linux) u r using.   http://eclipsesource.com/en/downloads/eclipse-helios-download/

Answer (score 1):

When using Eclipse Juno (classic) and Apache Cordova (phonegap) 2.5 you can enable syntax highlighting and code completion:

Help -> Install Software Work with... Select your eclipse version (juno) In the selection box below scroll to the entry "Web, XML, Java, ... " and expand it.

Select

Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools 
Eclipse Web Developer Tools 
Eclipse XML Developer Editors and Tools 
JavaScript Development Tools 
Web Page Editor

and then Next to install them.

Now you should have HTML, JS syntax highlighting and code completion.

Answer (score 0):

Android has given a bundle pack for developing Phonegap apps. Here is the link of ADT bundle pack

1) Just download latest ADT-Bundle pack [Mac](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#mac-bundle) or [Windows 32bit](http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030.zip) or [Windows 64bit](http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030.zip)

2) Download the MDS AppLaud plugin to Eclipse -> Help -> Install New Software to https://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/tags/r1.2/download

That's it.

With a single download, the ADT Bundle includes everything you need to begin developing apps:

```
Eclipse + ADT plugin
Android SDK Tools
Android Platform-tools
The latest Android platform
The latest Android system image for the emulator
```

I highly recommend [Brackets](http://download.brackets.io/) to be used as code editor.